radical subgroups in fusion systems
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a fusion system over a $p$-group $P$. Fix a subgroup $Q$ of $P$. $Q$ is said to be radical if $\text{O}_p(\text{Aut}_\mathcal{F}(Q))=\text{Inn} (Q).$
My question: In a saturated fusion system, does there always exist a radical subgroup?

This question is on a very specialized topic and would probably be more suitable for mathoverflow.
